# c# how to modify the control's property

Tags: c#

I get a control from customers. just a dll file.

it like a textbox. use user to input the value, now as called **SUTextBox**.

it have a property **"IsemailValidation=true",** then it can validate email address.

now ,I have a request like this. if user input value ,then validate it ,

if user don't input value ,then don't validate ,just get empty data(this control cannot be empty if set **IsemailValidation=true**).

The key question is that,if I set **IsemailValidation=true**. this textbox cannot be empty.
and I want to it can be empty or have valid email address.

Can I set the property somewhere dynamic?

Comment: Set this property to false and do your own email validation?  Sounds like a buggy bit of a control.

Comment: do as paddy said or you can override IsemailValidation if possible, look at its definition

Comment: if like you said ,then I can use textbox directly. hah ,I just don't want to validation by my own client validation.so I use their control. but control cannot allow empty, that's the key question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your `SUTextBox` should have some `TextChanged` event and we can handle this event like this:

```
sUTextBox1.TextChanged += (s,e) => {
   bool validate = !(sUTextBox1.Text == "");
   if(sUTextBox1.IsemailValidation!=validate) 
     sUTextBox1.IsemailValidation = validate;
};
```

Comment: I checked ,basically don't have events. only have like onload,or unload ,it's sad

Comment: @chengdu.jack what kind of UI technology are you using? If there is not any similar event, that's kind of bad design indeed.

Comment: Web2.0, haha ,I agree with you! it's sad